# How can I hide top slider from the remaining blog pages except the first blog page?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to hide the top slider part from the blog pages but in the first blog page I want to keep it. You can check this link: http://site4preview.site90.net/wordpress/ . There are two pages in the page navigation. I want to hide the slider from all pages starting from the page number 2 except 1. So is there any way to do it please ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you solved your problem, am I right?

Comment: No, I haven't solved it yet. Have you understood my problem clearly please ?

Comment: Just now I think I got it. You are saying the pagination, right? you want the slider to appear on the first page navigation but not in the other am I right? Use `is_paged()`

Comment: Great. Exactly. There are now only 2 pages now as there only a few post(the site is under construction) but more pages will come. So when I am on the page 1 or home page (I mean : http://site4preview.site90.net/wordpress/ ) this will be as it is appearing now but when I will go through the other blog pages (for example: http://site4preview.site90.net/wordpress/page/2/) or others respectively I want to hide the slider and signup form. So can you understand my problem clearly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if that page is a "pagination" page, for this you must use `is_paged()`.

Try this.

```
<?php
    if( !is_paged() ) {
        //Slider Goes Here
    }
?>
```

**EDIT:**

You could just hide with CSS, it's not the best solution, but it get the job done.

If you have multiple sliders you could use this cascade to be more precise

```
.paged .block-content .widget-area .recent-posts-flexslider-class { 
    display: none 
}
```

just hide all sliders under the paged pages

```
.paged .recent-posts-flexslider-class {
    display: none;
}
```

or, if you know CSS hide the div you want utilizing the class `.paged` that shows only when you're visualizing a paged template

Comment: Right. I am using the Wp-pagenavi for pagination. Also I am not expert in PHP, so can you help me by writing the full code please ? Thanks.

Comment: #1 I could but I don't know how is your source code #2 It's a good way to practice it. (like for me helping you and other are a good way to practice my WP skills, my english and in the same time help people) Edit your question and put the part of the code that shows the slider.

Comment: Yes, you're right. That's a best way to practicing by solving problem, I can understand the different features but I can't write PHP function fully still. Thanks for your suggestion but for the slider I am using a plugin also and I am using it as a widget, so which code will I provide here ? Also you can do it in another way. As it is a block based theme. So you can do it by hiding the full slider block without using the slider source code when the page is 2 or next....

Comment: If it's a a widget it's coming from a sidebar. you wrap the `<?php get_sidebar() ?>` in the if statement i wrote up. `<?php if( !is_paged() ) { get_sidebar(); } ?>` but all the widgets are going to be hidden.

Comment: There are other blocks also in the sidebar so I can't hide the full sidebar. Also what do I have to write into the `<?php if(!is_paged(.....Here.....))?>` ?

Comment: In this case I think there's nothing you can do, because if the widget don't give you the options you can't hide it. Unless you create a slider. What you can do to HIDE the slider you could use a CSS to hide on paged navigation pages `.paged .block-content .widget-area .recent-posts-flexslider-class { display: none }` I've used all this cascade in case you use it in other places, but you could do it like this `.paged .recent-posts-flexslider-class { display: none }`

Comment: In this case I think it will hide the slider from all the pages including the home page I mean page-1. Right ?

Comment: No, it'll not hide on the first page